# Approximation of Group Schemes over valuation rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

In his paper [Approximation des schémas en groupes, quasi compacts sur un corps](https://eudml.org/doc/87279), Daniel Perrin shows that every quasi compact group scheme over a field then it is an inverse limit of group schemes of finite type.

Is there a similar result for group schemes over a valuation ring?

Answer (score 3):

It is true if you make some mild assumption on the valuation ring $R$ and the Hopf algebra $H=R[G]$.
For example, let's assume that $H$ is free over $R$, and that $R$ is a discrete valuation ring.
The main ingredient in the proof in the paper you cited is the following fact about co-algebras over a field: if $C$ is a coalgebra over a field $K$, and $V\subseteq C$ is a finite dimensional subspace, then there exists a finite dimensional subcoalgebra $D\subseteq C$ such that $V\subseteq D$. The proof goes almost the same for discrete valuation rings as for fields. We need to assumption on $H$ to make sure that nothing too singular will occur.

Comment: But $G$ may not be affine... Why do you need $R$ to be a DVR? Do you mind elaborating?